# Teradata - Removing Banker's Rounding with changing settings

Tags: teradata, bankers-rounding, bankers-algorithm

I need to mimic a calculation in excel.  We have to get the excact answer.  The calculation is rounded at several points.  Excel round X.5 up.  It looks like Teradata is using banker's rounding (round X.5 to the even #).

I cannot change the setting in the company database.  Is there any syntax I can use?

I have a temporary fix with a case statement but am hoping there is a better solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show an example of the query you are using.  Also, identify the data-types of the columns used in your calculation.

Answer (score 1):

set RoundHalfwayMagUp to TRUE in dbscontrol.

Comment: Trouble is that he indicated that changing that setting may not be an option. That was my first thought as well.